# What will be the correct Redirect URI after authentication for MSAdal in ionic 4?

Tags: ionic-framework, azure-active-directory

My question is: when I authenticated from my Ionic 4 app I want to redirect it to the app root page. What will be the correct Redirect URI for authContext.acquireTokenAsync ? I have an error.

Answer from Microsoft.

```
 The reply url specified in the request does not match the reply urls configured for the application: '1111111111111111111111111111'.
```

I use such code.

```
let authContext: AuthenticationContext = this.msAdal.createAuthenticationContext('https://login.windows.net/common');

authContext.acquireTokenAsync('https://graph.windows.net', 'ClinetID', 'http://localhost:8000','','')
    .then((authResponse: AuthenticationResult) => {
      console.log('Token is' , authResponse.accessToken);
      console.log('Token will expire on', authResponse.expiresOn);
    })
    .catch((e: any) => console.log('Authentication failed', e));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to register an app as Native app on Active directory with the suggested redirect url or use a cutom redirect url.

[image]

I use `urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob` as the redirect url, so the code should be

```
authContext.acquireTokenAsync('https://graph.windows.net','<Your Native App client ID>' , 'urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob', '', null)
```

**Note** :You must keep the redirect url in azure portal and the redirect url in your code the same.

Comment: Tony Ju,good day! Thank you very much for answer. It is work. I received token and time when token will expire. Can you explain please what I need to do with this token next ?

Comment: @anton_klochko Glad it works. This answer is for 'when I authenticated from my Ionic 4 app I want to redirect it to the app root page'. For your new issue, can you please post a new one with more details? Actually,I don't know what you need.

Comment: @anton_klochko Please accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in). Then this issue can be closed. Thank you.

Comment: In ionic 5, the app is stopped without going to the login page. Why?